# Has Iron Man visited the ''quantum city''?

Tags: marvel, comics, iron-man

From *Avengers: Endgame* we have seen that the superheroes used the quantum realm to travel back in time. Also, we have seen in *Ant-Man and the Wasp* that there is a [quantum city](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/avengers-4-ant-man-wasp-quantum-realm-city-subatomic/) present in the quantum realm.

In MCU we don't see Iron Man visiting the quantum city so has he ever visited the quantum city in comics?

[image: The city in the quantum realm as seen in AMATW; it is a small city for the already small place encased in a bubble/dome on a “branch”]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Microverse city" was developed exclusively as an ['*easter-egg*'](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EasterEgg) in the Ant-man sequel movie. You can see the concept art on [Concept Artist Jackson Sze](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Jackson_Sze)'s [instagram account](https://www.instagram.com/p/BxP7jGqlYdl/?utm_source=ig_embed). As such, Iron Man can't have gone there (in the comics) because it doesn't exist in the comics.

> Microverse City developed for Antman and the Wasp. I wonder if Scott Lang made it here during his unscheduled stay in the Quantum Realm. You can catch the briefest glimpse of this when Hank and Janet leave the Quantum Realm.
>
> [image: Concept art of the Quantum Realm; a tree like structure can be seen in the middle with roots coming towards it. A “branch” of the tree has a city built upon it]

---

Notably, although members of the Avengers (including Iron Man) and Fantastic 4 have been to the so-called [*"Microverse"*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Microverse) that exists in the 616 universe, **it's in fact *[a parallel universe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcXmB.png)* accessible by traveling through quantum space rather than being part of the quantum realm proper.** [An easy mistake to make](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/234906/20774).

> **Reed:** *We now know this is actually **extra-dimensional space** achieved through our mass stabilized passage through the zero point.*
>
> **She-Hulk:** *How's that again? I though we were shrinking.*
>
> **Johnny:** *We were, Jen. But what Reed's saying is that somehow **pops us through** into a parallel universe. We still call it the "Micro-Verse" because... well, "A rose by any other name..." right?*

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

The [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/234902/58193) is correct in saying that the city in the quantum realm is an Easter Egg in the film. However, that doesn’t mean Iron Man has never been to the Microverse (as the quantum realm is known in the comics) in the comics before. In fact he has been and even visited a city whilst there.

In *Avengers Vol. 4* Issue 32 the Avengers have received a signal from an unknown Avenger coming from the Microverse. They go in to save the Avenger who turns out to be Janet Van Dyne, the Wasp... sounds familiar? They find Janet in a city in the Microverse.

[image: The Avengers struggle to adapt to the Microverse but press in tracking the signal to a city. They enter the city in hiding viewing its inhabitants from the shadows and seeing the ruined buildings.]

Comment: The microverse is, of course, later revealed to be a parallel dimension rather than existing within the quantum realm itself.

Comment: So it means that more than one Avengers have been in the microverse city

Comment: @codeczar The Microverse is a lot more developed than the quantum realm.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot ok didn't know much about the microverse before

Comment: @Valorum for all intents and purposes they are the same thing. It’s even referred to as the Quantum Realm on a few occasions.

Comment: Well, no. Johnny Storm points out in Fantastic Four #282 that **although they're going to carry on calling it that, that's not what it is.**

Comment: @codeczar - Yes, but you were asking about a city that exists in the quantum realm. The *[microverse](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Microverse)* doesn't exist *in* the quantum realm (it's merely accessible through it, and [other means not involving the quantum realm at all](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/prometheus-pit/4055-57222/)), so surely it doesn't count...